# all possible combinations from a set of sets (n choose k)

Tags: c#, set, combinatorics

Given several sets such as `{1,2,3,4}`,`{1,2}`,`{1}`,`{1,2,3,}`,..., and a number `k` such that the combination that ought to be formed is exactly of length `k`, *how would one go about generating a unique combination of length `k` if I can only choose one number from each set?*

There are exactly k number of sets to choose from. I'm looking for the most efficient way to do this in c#.

Intuitively i tried(though i'm not sure it is correct) generating all possible combinations for each set then concatenating each i'th combination from each set with the corresponding i'th combination from subsequent sets to form a `k` long unique combination but I'm sure there is a general case for this type of question.

Can anyone please offer some tips or advise? Specifically which math or computer science topic this falls under and how these questions are typically solved?

in the snippet below a string in the array theSets would be for example "31"
this means that k = 2 (length of a string in theSets) and there are two sets one of which is {1,2,3} and {1}. with these sets, generate all the unique combinations and provide a count

```
private int combicount(string[] theSets)
    {
        int size = theSets[0].Length;
        int count = 0;
        List<HashSet<int>> l = new List<HashSet<int>>();
        foreach (string s in theSets)
        {
            foreach (char c in s)
            {
                HashSet<int> h = new HashSet<int>();
                for (int n = 1; n <= int.Parse(c.ToString()); n++)
                {
                    h.Add(n);
                }
                l.Add(h);
            }

            //toDO - generate all unique combinations by picking exactly 1 from each set in l
            //toDO - count the number of unique combinations generated
        }


        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Post code you have tried.

Comment: in presented example sets are ordered, ex: {1,2,3..}. Is this is a true?

Comment: Are you asking for one combination, or an enumeration of all possibilities? If you're picking one number from each set I don't understand why you are generating combinations from each set. What does unique mean here? Uniqueness surely relates to generating multiple combinations?

Comment: This problem is typically solved by first solving it by hand, then converting your hand solution to an algorithm, then implementing the algorithm. [Cartesian product of n lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776763/cartesian-product-of-n-lists). By the way, your problem is not "n choose k". "n choose k" is "given a set of n elements, choose k of them." You want "Given k sets, choose one from each."

Comment: See my answer in this [previous](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19282073/2330053) SO question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get all posible combinations of array of arrays in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280746/get-all-posible-combinations-of-array-of-arrays-in-vb-net)

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you for pointing me to the right direction with the topic of 'Cartesian product' i found some good insight on this. Its certainly what i'm trying to achieve, just looking for an implementation now in c#

Comment: See my previous comment on how to solve it, plus a link to a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to solve it like this:

```
    private void CombineSets()
    {
        var mySets = new List<HashSet<int>>();
        mySets.Add(new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
        mySets.Add(new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2 });
        mySets.Add(new HashSet<int>() { 1 });
        mySets.Add(new HashSet<int>() { 1, 2, 3 });

        var result = new HashSet<int>();


        while (mySets.Count > 0)
        {
            //get the smallest set
            var set = mySets.OrderBy(x => x.Count).First();
            //remove the set from the collection as we do not need it anymore (we got our value)
            mySets.Remove(set);
            //remove what is in the result from the set (as we only want unique values)
            set.ExceptWith(result);
            //then add the first value from the remaining values to our result set
            result.Add(set.First());

        }
    }
```

To make this more efficient you could also sort the list before the while loop. This at least solves the first few lines of your question.

Hope this helps :)